# Sharing folders in different networks with VMWare

Tags: vmware, shared-folders

I have a VMware host that is on one network, running a VM that is on another network.
My client is on the same network as the host.

Is there any way to 'physically' share a folder on the VMware host with the VM, so that the folder can be accessible both from my client, and from the VM?

All computers are running Windows.